# Can't use value placed in data in template. Only props value works

Tags: vue.js

I am getting value from `props`. And depend on it change class. Here is working code:

```
<div class="modal" :class="{'is-active': aa}" >
```

But when I try to make check based in `isActive` value from `data`:

```
<div class="modal" :class="{'is-active': isActive}" >
```

Nothing do not working. Modal window do not appearing. Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/tagdjyrL/

Example will stop working if change `aa` to `isActive`

Comment: What is wrong with the example? modal is opening and closing well

Comment: It will stop working if change `aa` to `isActive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `isActive` from your `data` to `computed`.

```
computed:
{
  isActive() { return this.aa }
}
```

And edit your `closeModalWindow`:

```
  closeModalWindow: function()
  {
    this.$emit('my-event', false)
  }
```

You can't directly edit your `isActive` now, so just pass `false` as payload.

https://jsfiddle.net/tagdjyrL/11/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but could you explain why my code is stop working?

Comment: If your `isActive` property is kept in `data` it's value is taken from `aa` prop when component is rendered (`false` in this case) and it won't automatically change when `aa` is changed. If you want it to update when `aa` changes, `isActive` has to be a `computed` property.

Comment: Why I should do `this.$emit('my-event', false)` ? Am I right understand that it will emit to parent?

Comment: Yes, you tell your parent that modal shouldn't be active anymore. The parent updates it's `isActive` property to `false` thus hiding the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed this part of documentation: if you use prop in data, like this:

```
props: ['modalOpen'],
data () {
  return {
    isActive: this.modalOpen
  }
}
```

your `openModal` value will be used only once, as initial value for `isActive` property. So, when you change the `openModal`, the `isActive` will remain unchanged. But when you use `openModal` in computed property, like this:

```
props: ['modalOpen'],
computed: {
  isActive () {
    return this.modalOpen
  }
}
```

the `isActive` value remains reactive, will reflect the `openModal` changes.

So, when you use this principle in you subcomponent, you will not need to use $emit:

In parent:

```
<template>
  <my-modal :openModal="isActive">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        isActive: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In modal:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isActive">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['modalOpen'],
    computed: {
      isActive () {
        return this.modalOpen
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And now you can show / hide your modal with changing the `isActive` property to true / false in your parent component, no need to use the $emit method.